# Python pandas calculate rolling stock beta using rolling apply to groupby object in vectorized fashion

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, apply, beta

I have a large data frame, df, containing 4 columns:

```
             id           period  ret_1m   mkt_ret_1m
131146       CAN00WG0     199609 -0.1538    0.047104
133530       CAN00WG0     199610 -0.0455   -0.014143
135913       CAN00WG0     199611  0.0000    0.040926
138334       CAN00WG0     199612  0.2952    0.008723
140794       CAN00WG0     199701 -0.0257    0.039916
143274       CAN00WG0     199702 -0.0038   -0.025442
145754       CAN00WG0     199703 -0.2992   -0.049279
148246       CAN00WG0     199704 -0.0919   -0.005948
150774       CAN00WG0     199705  0.0595    0.122322
153318       CAN00WG0     199706 -0.0337    0.045765

             id           period  ret_1m   mkt_ret_1m
160980       CAN00WH0     199709  0.0757    0.079293
163569       CAN00WH0     199710 -0.0741   -0.044000
166159       CAN00WH0     199711  0.1000   -0.014644
168782       CAN00WH0     199712 -0.0909   -0.007072
171399       CAN00WH0     199801 -0.0100    0.001381
174022       CAN00WH0     199802  0.1919    0.081924
176637       CAN00WH0     199803  0.0085    0.050415
179255       CAN00WH0     199804 -0.0168    0.018393
181880       CAN00WH0     199805  0.0427   -0.051279
184516       CAN00WH0     199806 -0.0656   -0.011516

             id           period  ret_1m   mkt_ret_1m
143275       CAN00WO0     199702 -0.1176   -0.025442
145755       CAN00WO0     199703 -0.0074   -0.049279
148247       CAN00WO0     199704 -0.0075   -0.005948
150775       CAN00WO0     199705  0.0451    0.122322
```

etc.

I am attempting to calculate a common financial measure, known as beta, using a function, that takes two of the columns, ret_1m, the monthly stock_return, and ret_1m_mkt, the market 1 month return for the same period (period_id).  I want to apply a function (calc_beta) to calculate the 12-month result of this function on a 12 month rolling basis.

To do this, I am creating a groupby object:

```
grp = df.groupby('id')
```

What I would like to do is use something like:

```
period = 12
for stock, sub_df in grp:
    arg = sub_df[['ret_1m', 'mkt_ret_1m']]
    beta = pd.rolling_apply(arg, period, calc_beta, min_periods = period)
```

Now, here is the first problem.  According to the documentation, pd.rolling_apply arg can be either a series or a data frame.  However, it appears that the data frame I supply is converted into a numpy array that can only contain one column of data, rather than the two I have tried to supply.  So my code below for calc_beta will not work, because I need to pass both the stock and market returns:

```
def calc_beta(np_array)
    s = np_array[:,0] # stock returns are column zero from numpy array
    m = np_array[:,1] # market returns are column one from numpy array

    covariance = np.cov(s,m) # Calculate covariance between stock and market
    beta = covariance[0,1]/covariance[1,1]
return beta
```

So my questions are as follows, I think it makes sense to list them in this way:

```
(i)  How can I pass a data frame/multiple series/numpy array with more than one column to calc_beta using rolling_apply?
(ii) How can I return more than one value (e.g. the beta) from the calc_beta function? 
(iii) Having calculated rolling quantities, how can I recombined with the original dataframe df so that I have the rolling quantities corresponding to the correct date in the period column?
(iv) Is there a better (vectorized) way of achieving this?  I have seen some similar questions using e.g. df.apply(pd.rolling_apply,period,??) but I did not understand how these worked.
```

I gather that rolling_apply previously was unable to handle data frames, but the documentations suggests that it is now able to do so.  My pandas.**version** is 0.16.1.

Thanks for any help! I have lost 1.5 days trying to figure this out and am totally stumped.

Ultimately, what I want is something like this:

```
             id           period  ret_1m   mkt_ret_1m  beta  other_quantities
131146       CAN00WG0     199609 -0.1538    0.047104  0.521  xxx
133530       CAN00WG0     199610 -0.0455   -0.014143  0.627  xxxx
135913       CAN00WG0     199611  0.0000    0.040926  0.341  xxx
138334       CAN00WG0     199612  0.2952    0.008723  0.567  xx
140794       CAN00WG0     199701 -0.0257    0.039916  0.4612 xxx
143274       CAN00WG0     199702 -0.0038   -0.025442  0.215  xxx
145754       CAN00WG0     199703 -0.2992   -0.049279  0.4678  xxx
148246       CAN00WG0     199704 -0.0919   -0.005948  -0.4225  xxx
150774       CAN00WG0     199705  0.0595    0.122322  0.780  xxx
153318       CAN00WG0     199706 -0.0337    0.045765  0.623  xxx

             id           period  ret_1m   mkt_ret_1m  beta  other_quantities
160980       CAN00WH0     199709  0.0757    0.079293  -0.913  xx
163569       CAN00WH0     199710 -0.0741   -0.044000  0.894  xxx
166159       CAN00WH0     199711  0.1000   -0.014644  0.563  xxx
168782       CAN00WH0     199712 -0.0909   -0.007072  0.734  xxx
171399       CAN00WH0     199801 -0.0100    0.001381  0.894  xxxx
174022       CAN00WH0     199802  0.1919    0.081924  0.789  xx
176637       CAN00WH0     199803  0.0085    0.050415  0.1563  xxxx
179255       CAN00WH0     199804 -0.0168    0.018393  -0.64  xxxx
181880       CAN00WH0     199805  0.0427   -0.051279  -0.742  xxx
184516       CAN00WH0     199806 -0.0656   -0.011516  0.925  xxx

             id           period  ret_1m   mkt_ret_1m  beta
143275       CAN00WO0     199702 -0.1176   -0.025442  -1.52  xx
145755       CAN00WO0     199703 -0.0074   -0.049279  -0.632  xxx
148247       CAN00WO0     199704 -0.0075   -0.005948  1.521  xx
150775       CAN00WO0     199705  0.0451    0.122322  0.0321  xxx
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def rolling_apply(df, period, func, min_periods=None):
    if min_periods is None:
        min_periods = period
    result = pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.index)

    for i in range(1, len(df)):
        sub_df = df.iloc[max(i-period, 0):i,:] #get a subsample to run
        if len(sub_df) >= min_periods:
            idx = sub_df.index[-1]+1 # mind the forward looking bias,your return in time t should not be inclued in the beta calculating in time t
            result[idx] = func(sub_df)
    return result
```

I fix a forward looking bias for [Happy001's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34804485/5817977). It's a finance problem, so it should be cautious.

I find that [vlmercado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44116341/14640647)'s answer is so wrong. If you simply use pd.rolling_cov and pd.rolling_var you are making mistakes in finance. Firstly, it's obvious that the second stock CAN00WH0 do not have any NaN beta, since it use the return of CAN00WG0, which is wrong at all. Secondly, consider such a situation: a stock suspended for ten years, and you can also get that sample into your beta calculating.

I find that pandas.rolling also works for Timestamp, you can see how in my answer above if interested. I change the code of  [Happy001's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34804485/5817977) . It's not the fastest way, but is at least 20x faster than the origin code.

```
crsp_daily['date']=pd.to_datetime(crsp_daily['date'])
crsp_daily=crsp_daily.set_index('date') # rolling needs a time serie index
crsp_daily.index=pd.DatetimeIndex(crsp_daily.index)
calc=crsp_daily[['permno','ret','mkt_ret']]
grp = calc.groupby('permno') #rolling beta for each stock
beta=pd.DataFrame()
for stock, sub_df in grp:
        sub2_df=sub_df[['ret','mkt_ret']].sort_index() 
        beta_m = sub2_df.rolling('1825d',min_periods=150).cov() # 5yr rolling beta , note that d for day, and you cannot use w/m/y, s/d are availiable.
        beta_m['beta']=beta_m['ret']/beta_m['mkt_ret']
        beta_m=beta_m.xs('mkt_ret',level=1,axis=0)
        beta=beta.append(pd.merge(sub_df,pd.DataFrame(beta_m['beta'])))
beta=beta.reset_index()
beta=beta[['date','permno','beta']]
```

Answer (score 9):

Try pd.rolling_cov() and pd.rolling.var() as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''              id  period  ret_1m  mkt_ret_1m
    131146  CAN00WG0  199609 -0.1538    0.047104
    133530  CAN00WG0  199610 -0.0455   -0.014143
    135913  CAN00WG0  199611  0.0000    0.040926
    138334  CAN00WG0  199612  0.2952    0.008723
    140794  CAN00WG0  199701 -0.0257    0.039916
    143274  CAN00WG0  199702 -0.0038   -0.025442
    145754  CAN00WG0  199703 -0.2992   -0.049279
    148246  CAN00WG0  199704 -0.0919   -0.005948
    150774  CAN00WG0  199705  0.0595    0.122322
    153318  CAN00WG0  199706 -0.0337    0.045765
    160980  CAN00WH0  199709  0.0757    0.079293
    163569  CAN00WH0  199710 -0.0741   -0.044000
    166159  CAN00WH0  199711  0.1000   -0.014644
    168782  CAN00WH0  199712 -0.0909   -0.007072
    171399  CAN00WH0  199801 -0.0100    0.001381
    174022  CAN00WH0  199802  0.1919    0.081924
    176637  CAN00WH0  199803  0.0085    0.050415
    179255  CAN00WH0  199804 -0.0168    0.018393
    181880  CAN00WH0  199805  0.0427   -0.051279
    184516  CAN00WH0  199806 -0.0656   -0.011516
    143275  CAN00WO0  199702 -0.1176   -0.025442
    145755  CAN00WO0  199703 -0.0074   -0.049279
    148247  CAN00WO0  199704 -0.0075   -0.005948
    150775  CAN00WO0  199705  0.0451    0.122322'''), sep='\s+')

    df['beta'] = pd.rolling_cov(df['ret_1m'], df['mkt_ret_1m'], window=6) / pd.rolling_var(df['mkt_ret_1m'], window=6)

print df
```

Output:

```
              id  period  ret_1m  mkt_ret_1m      beta
131146  CAN00WG0  199609 -0.1538    0.047104       NaN
133530  CAN00WG0  199610 -0.0455   -0.014143       NaN
135913  CAN00WG0  199611  0.0000    0.040926       NaN
138334  CAN00WG0  199612  0.2952    0.008723       NaN
140794  CAN00WG0  199701 -0.0257    0.039916       NaN
143274  CAN00WG0  199702 -0.0038   -0.025442 -1.245908
145754  CAN00WG0  199703 -0.2992   -0.049279  2.574464
148246  CAN00WG0  199704 -0.0919   -0.005948  2.657887
150774  CAN00WG0  199705  0.0595    0.122322  1.371090
153318  CAN00WG0  199706 -0.0337    0.045765  1.494095
160980  CAN00WH0  199709  0.0757    0.079293  1.616520
163569  CAN00WH0  199710 -0.0741   -0.044000  1.630411
166159  CAN00WH0  199711  0.1000   -0.014644  0.651220
168782  CAN00WH0  199712 -0.0909   -0.007072  0.652148
171399  CAN00WH0  199801 -0.0100    0.001381  0.724120
174022  CAN00WH0  199802  0.1919    0.081924  1.542782
176637  CAN00WH0  199803  0.0085    0.050415  1.605407
179255  CAN00WH0  199804 -0.0168    0.018393  1.571015
181880  CAN00WH0  199805  0.0427   -0.051279  1.139972
184516  CAN00WH0  199806 -0.0656   -0.011516  1.101890
143275  CAN00WO0  199702 -0.1176   -0.025442  1.372437
145755  CAN00WO0  199703 -0.0074   -0.049279  0.031939
148247  CAN00WO0  199704 -0.0075   -0.005948 -0.535855
150775  CAN00WO0  199705  0.0451    0.122322  0.341747
```

Comment: How about rolling R^2?

Comment: Thanks! For anyone who sees this in the future, `pd.rolling_cov` was changed to `df.rolling(window).cov`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/window.html

Answer (score 5):

I guess `pd.rolling_apply` doesn't help in this case since it seems to me that it essentially only takes a `Series` (Even if a dataframe is passed, it's processing one column a time). But you can always write your own rolling_apply that takes a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''              id  period  ret_1m  mkt_ret_1m
131146  CAN00WG0  199609 -0.1538    0.047104
133530  CAN00WG0  199610 -0.0455   -0.014143
135913  CAN00WG0  199611  0.0000    0.040926
138334  CAN00WG0  199612  0.2952    0.008723
140794  CAN00WG0  199701 -0.0257    0.039916
143274  CAN00WG0  199702 -0.0038   -0.025442
145754  CAN00WG0  199703 -0.2992   -0.049279
148246  CAN00WG0  199704 -0.0919   -0.005948
150774  CAN00WG0  199705  0.0595    0.122322
153318  CAN00WG0  199706 -0.0337    0.045765
160980  CAN00WH0  199709  0.0757    0.079293
163569  CAN00WH0  199710 -0.0741   -0.044000
166159  CAN00WH0  199711  0.1000   -0.014644
168782  CAN00WH0  199712 -0.0909   -0.007072
171399  CAN00WH0  199801 -0.0100    0.001381
174022  CAN00WH0  199802  0.1919    0.081924
176637  CAN00WH0  199803  0.0085    0.050415
179255  CAN00WH0  199804 -0.0168    0.018393
181880  CAN00WH0  199805  0.0427   -0.051279
184516  CAN00WH0  199806 -0.0656   -0.011516
143275  CAN00WO0  199702 -0.1176   -0.025442
145755  CAN00WO0  199703 -0.0074   -0.049279
148247  CAN00WO0  199704 -0.0075   -0.005948
150775  CAN00WO0  199705  0.0451    0.122322'''), sep='\s+')



def calc_beta(df):
    np_array = df.values
    s = np_array[:,0] # stock returns are column zero from numpy array
    m = np_array[:,1] # market returns are column one from numpy array

    covariance = np.cov(s,m) # Calculate covariance between stock and market
    beta = covariance[0,1]/covariance[1,1]
    return beta

def rolling_apply(df, period, func, min_periods=None):
    if min_periods is None:
        min_periods = period
    result = pd.Series(np.nan, index=df.index)

    for i in range(1, len(df)+1):
        sub_df = df.iloc[max(i-period, 0):i,:] #I edited here
        if len(sub_df) >= min_periods:
            idx = sub_df.index[-1]
            result[idx] = func(sub_df)
    return result

df['beta'] = np.nan
grp = df.groupby('id')
period = 6 #I'm using 6  to see some not NaN values, since sample data don't have longer than 12 groups
for stock, sub_df in grp:
    beta = rolling_apply(sub_df[['ret_1m','mkt_ret_1m']], period, calc_beta, min_periods = period)  
    beta.name = 'beta'
    df.update(beta)
print df
```

Output

```
            id  period  ret_1m  mkt_ret_1m      beta
131146  CAN00WG0  199609 -0.1538    0.047104       NaN
133530  CAN00WG0  199610 -0.0455   -0.014143       NaN
135913  CAN00WG0  199611  0.0000    0.040926       NaN
138334  CAN00WG0  199612  0.2952    0.008723       NaN
140794  CAN00WG0  199701 -0.0257    0.039916       NaN
143274  CAN00WG0  199702 -0.0038   -0.025442 -1.245908
145754  CAN00WG0  199703 -0.2992   -0.049279  2.574464
148246  CAN00WG0  199704 -0.0919   -0.005948  2.657887
150774  CAN00WG0  199705  0.0595    0.122322  1.371090
153318  CAN00WG0  199706 -0.0337    0.045765  1.494095
...          ...     ...     ...         ...       ...
171399  CAN00WH0  199801 -0.0100    0.001381       NaN
174022  CAN00WH0  199802  0.1919    0.081924  1.542782
176637  CAN00WH0  199803  0.0085    0.050415  1.605407
179255  CAN00WH0  199804 -0.0168    0.018393  1.571015
181880  CAN00WH0  199805  0.0427   -0.051279  1.139972
184516  CAN00WH0  199806 -0.0656   -0.011516  1.101890
143275  CAN00WO0  199702 -0.1176   -0.025442       NaN
145755  CAN00WO0  199703 -0.0074   -0.049279       NaN
148247  CAN00WO0  199704 -0.0075   -0.005948       NaN
150775  CAN00WO0  199705  0.0451    0.122322       NaN
```

Comment: Thanks.  When i = period (e.g. period = 12), surely the line sub_df = df.iloc[max(i-period, 0):i+1,:] will result in df.iloc[0:period + 1,:], e.g. when period = 12, df.iloc[0:13,:], when in fact one wants it to start at df.iloc[0:period - 1,:] as 0 : 12 would involve 13 elements, rather than the 12 desired?

Comment: Also, would it be faster to use shift(period) on df, rather than looping over index stuff?  I gather using for loops is very slow because it uses interpreted python, rather than panda's underlying C++ libraries.  Quite keen to learn how to do everything in that manner if possible!

Comment: And how do I recombine the result with the original dataframe, such that each result (beta) corresponds to (is in the same row as) the correct period value (e.g. 199503)?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why this line is here:              idx = sub_df.index[-1] # what is this for?

Comment: You don't want the first sub_df to be empty when `i=0`. So either do `sub_df = df.iloc[max(i-period+1, 0):i+1,:]` (I was wrong missing +1) or shift the index `for i in range(1, len(df)+1):`

Comment: You are apply a function to a rolling window of data. That's not the same as shift. You need to do some kind of looping, either in Python, or if performance is critical, in Cython just like Pandas did. Check out roll_generic https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/algos.pyx

Comment: It seems your index is unique, so you can use index to update / join back to original dataframe (see edit). `idx = sub_df.index[-1] ` is to align `beta` computed from a window with the last row of that window.

Comment: Thanks Happy001.  On the sub_df.index[-1], is that because the last value of i is len(df) + 1? struggling to wrap my head around this!  And secondly, rather than return a single series (Result[idx]), it would be much more flexible to return a data frame so that I can update df with 3 new columns (e.g. beta, R squared, and another).  I think this is a very common problem actually, so getting a fully worked solution up here will help others!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, since nobody ask the mutil-variable rolling regression in python, I also find a way to slove this problem. The key is that first stack them into one column, and reshape the dataframe in function.

Here is the Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
from numba import jit 

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True,fastmath=True) # numba only support numpy but pandas, so pd.DataFrame is forbiddened.
def coefcalc(df,coefpos,varnum): 
# coefpos: which coef you need, for example I want alpha, so I would set the coefpos as 5 to obtain the alpha since the constant is in the last column in X. varnum: how many variables you put in df except "stkcd and date", in this sample, it's 7 (return,five fama factors, and a constant)

    if np.mod(df.shape[0],varnum)==0:
        df=df.reshape(df.shape[0]//varnum,varnum) # reshape the one column to n column for reg.
        Y=np.ascontiguousarray(df[:,0]) # rebuild a contigous numpy array for faster reg
        X=np.ascontiguousarray(df[:,1:])
        try:
            b=(np.linalg.inv(X.T@X))@X.T@Y
            result=b[coefpos]
        except:
            result=np.nan
        return result
    else:
        return np.nan
    
calc2=pd.read_csv(r'sample.csv')

# A way for rolling beta/alpha
calc2=calc2.set_index(['date','F_INFO_WINDCODE'])
calc2=calc2.dropna() # regression will drop Nan automatically
calc2=calc2.stack().reset_index().set_index('date') # put n columns into one columns, and let datetime64 variable (date) to be the index.
localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
print(localtime)
order_of_variable=5  # expect for y (return), start from zero.
total_number_variable=7 # stkcd/date/return/fama5/constant
required_sample=30*total_number_variable # Monthly data

# the parallel kwarg may require loops in def so I turn it off.
alphaest=calc2.groupby('F_INFO_WINDCODE').rolling('1095d',min_periods=required_sample)[0].apply(lambda x:coefcalc(x,5,7),engine='numba', raw=True,engine_kwargs={'nopython': True, 'nogil': True, 'parallel': False})

# as the pandas's document numba engine is faster than cpython when obs is over 1 million.
# you can check in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html , the numba engine part.

localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )
print(localtime)
```

[image: sample format]

Answer (score 1):

Good News! In pandas 1.3.0, a new method "Table" is added to rolling.apply, everything solved!

Here is an example code.

```
def coefcalc(df):
Y=np.ascontiguousarray(df[:,0]) # rebuild a contigous numpy array for faster reg
X=np.ascontiguousarray(df[:,1:])
try:
    b=(np.linalg.inv(X.T@X))@X.T@Y
    return np.nan,b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4]
except:
    return np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan

fama5=pd.read_csv('F-F_Research_Data_5_Factors_2x3.csv')
fama5=fama5.iloc[0:695,:].rename(columns={'Mkt-RF':'Mkt_Rf'})
fama5['date']=pd.to_datetime(fama5.date,format='%Y%m',errors='ignore')
for var in ['Mkt_Rf','SMB','HML','RMW','CMA','RF']:
    fama5[var]=pd.to_numeric(fama5[var])/100
    fama5[var]=fama5[var].astype('float64')

fama5=fama5.set_index('date')
fama5=fama5.drop('RF',axis=1)

beta=fama5.rolling('100d', method="table", min_periods=0).apply(coefcalc, raw=True, engine="numba")
```

You can download F-F_Research_Data_5_Factors_2x3.csv from Ken French's Homepage https://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/ftp/F-F_Research_Data_5_Factors_2x3_CSV.zip

Comment: Thank you! can this be done in a vectorized fashion?  Speed is of the essence ...

Comment: Hi, @Carl. I think that if you want a vectorized solution, you must come up with a formular that generate rolling betas first. I look around mathwork fourm and don't find any. I don't think it can be done using b=(X'X)^(-1)*(X'Y) which is the fastest and simplest way of calculating OLS coefs. Btw, I think that it would make a challenge on your computer's memory, and I think rolling.apply is quite fast, at least 20x~100x faster than other codes without rolling.apply.

Comment: On a related topic, at the moment I have some code that is pretty slow, that calculates multiple rolling averages.  Can I use method with the below to speed it up?  I'd probably be better using date-periods too, can that be done with table?

proc_list = ['liq_daily', 'liq_daily_usd', 'net_vwap_avg', 'px_avg', 'ln_ret', 'vwap_intra_net', 'liq_ret', vwap_intra_net_ret']
for p in [3, 5, 10, 22, 45, 67, 125, 252, 504, 756, 1260]:  
    px_df[[(q + '_' + str(p) + 'd') for q in proc_list]] = px_df.groupby('efcode')[proc_list].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(p, min_periods=int(0.8 * p)).mean())

Comment: I made this into a question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759901/pandas-rolling-moving-average-using-table-method-and-time-period

Comment: @Carl, I see your question. But I have two questions to ask. Firstly, your data generating process seems that one date can only be assign to one type of 'efcode', are you sure? If true, rolling is quite strange. Secondly, are you sure your demand is "rolling mean for some time periods", your code is telling another story, if you really want it, you should set the date as index first.

Comment: Hi Doralee.  (i)  efcode/date uniqueness is an artifact of the reproducible example.  In practice each efcode can have any date.  (ii)  I don't quite understand: my code should be calculating the rolling mean for each efcode's dataframe for each p.

Comment: @Carl, to the second question, e.g., your code is calculating the mean of two last sample, rather than the mean of last two days. BTW, I truely want you provide some true sample data so I can directly rewrite your code.

Comment: Thanks Doraelee.  OK, I can do that in the next couple of hours.  On (ii), my price data does not include weekends etc., so the mean of the last two samples generally is the mean of the last two trading days.  But, as you say, in the event of missing data/gaps (e.g. where a company has been suspended), I'd rather make absolutely sure that I am constrained by date ...

Comment: I have now added 60 days of actual data for two stocks.