# Python Panel replacement

Tags: python, pandas

Python no longer uses panel.  I am not skilled enough to think of an alternative and hoping someone knows of a work around.  I have been using the code below for some time but after an update it no longer works.  I would prefer to update the code then revert back to older unsupported versions.  the issue i am having is panel is deactivated.  can you see a work around to this problem?  for what i am trying to accomplish is find the beta of a stock.  i have taken the code from the following link

[Efficient Python Pandas Stock Beta Calculation on Many Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501277/efficient-python-pandas-stock-beta-calculation-on-many-dataframes)

```
def roll(df, w):
 # stack df.values w-times shifted once at each stack
 roll_array = np.dstack([df.values[i:i+w, :] for i in range(len(df.index) - w + 1)]).T
 # roll_array is now a 3-D array and can be read into
 # a pandas panel object
 panel = pd.Panel(roll_array, 
                 items=df.index[w-1:],
                 major_axis=df.columns,
                 minor_axis=pd.Index(range(w), name='roll'))
 # convert to dataframe and pivot + groupby
 # is now ready for any action normally performed
 # on a groupby object
 return panel.to_frame().unstack().T.groupby(level=0)

rdf = roll(df, 156)
```

Comment: Panels were replaced by multindex in later versions of pandas (see here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html)

Answer (score 0):

found the answer.  thought i would post in the off chance someone needed it.

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as stride
import pandas as pd

def roll(df, w, **kwargs):
    v = df.values
    d0, d1 = v.shape
    s0, s1 = v.strides

    a = stride(v, (d0 - (w - 1), w, d1), (s0, s0, s1))

    rolled_df = pd.concat({
        row: pd.DataFrame(values, columns=df.columns)
        for row, values in zip(df.index, a)
    })

    return rolled_df.groupby(level=0, **kwargs)

roll(df, 2).mean()
```

link to answer i found.

[link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878917/how-to-invoke-pandas-rolling-apply-with-parameters-from-multiple-column)