# Calculation of pearsons r and beta coefficient

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

How do i calculate the pearsons corr and Beta coefficient of every column in my dataframe against a dependent var

```
A             B            C              D           Sales
1             0            1              1             10
0             0            1              1             9 
1             1            1              0             15
```

Here A~D are independent and Sales is dependent, i want to find the r and beta coefficient of every column(Attribute)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501277/efficient-python-pandas-stock-beta-calculation-on-many-dataframes check this

Comment: i dont understand how i could use rolling beta in my case, i need to find the beta for col A against sales, B against sales and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for correlation:

```
df.corr()['Sales'][:-1]
```

or if your dataframe is too large, perhaps it is more efficient to do this:

```
df[df.columns[:-1]].apply(lambda x:x.corr(df['Sales']))
```

output:

```
A    0.628619
B    0.987829
C         NaN
D   -0.987829
```

And inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501277/efficient-python-pandas-stock-beta-calculation-on-many-dataframes) for beta:

```
def beta(df):
    # first column is the Sales
    X = df.values[:, [-1]]
    # prepend a column of ones for the intercept
    X = np.concatenate([np.ones_like(X), X], axis=1)
    # matrix algebra
    b = np.linalg.pinv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(df.values[:, :-1])
    return pd.Series(b[1], df.columns[:-1], name='Beta')

print(beta(df))
```

output:

```
A    1.129032e-01
B    1.774194e-01
C    1.110223e-15
D   -1.774194e-01
```

***EXPLANATION***:

You choose last column `Sales` as `X`, add a column of 1s to `X` to work as intercept and use this [closed form answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/23132) to calculate beta for all columns with `Sales` and finally return the betas as a Pandas Series indexed by column names.

Comment: in my case X would be the sales column?

Comment: Could you pls explain the function for beta

Answer (score 0):

You should check the docs for numpy, pandas, and scikit-learn, each of which has functions to get these.

For correlations, there's `numpy.corrcoef` in numpy and `pd.Series.corr` in pandas.

For regression coefficients, check out [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/) or `sklearn.linear_model` in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).

Comment: i did check them but i couldnt figure out how i could apply them in my case