# Pandas rolling moving average using table method and time period

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average, rolling-computation

I have some code that is pretty slow, that calculates multiple rolling averages over different time periods (e.g. 3 - 1260 days, or 5 years), but it is very slow and somewhat memory inefficient given that I am applying it to the full price history for around 50,000 listed global companies (with around 10 columns). I was recently made aware of the pandas 'table' method introduced in Pandas version 1.3, and wondered whether that can be used to make my code much faster, ideally, vectorized.

Ideally I would like to ensure that the data is consecutive, i.e. that I am not calculating the rolling average using stale data.  For example, if data is missing for months, weeks, or even years, I clearly don't want to include that data in the shorter moving averages: I would like the 22 day moving average to more-or-less correspond the the average over the previous month, not over any longer period.  I gather that one can do such a weighting in pandas 1.3 too, although I don't believe that was present earlier (when I originally wrote my code).

Reproducible Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *  #for BMonthEnd/MonthEnd()



df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    efcode = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10000),
    date = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(1990,1,1), end=pd.datetime(1990,1,1) + Day(9999), freq='D'),
    liq_daily = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000),
    liq_daily_usd = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000),
    net_vwap_avg = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000)
))

proc_list = ['liq_daily', 'liq_daily_usd', 'net_vwap_avg']
for p in [3, 5, 10, 22, 45, 67, 125, 252, 504, 756, 1260]:
    df[[(q + '_' + str(p) + 'd') for q in proc_list]] = df.groupby('efcode')[proc_list].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(p, min_periods=int( 0.8 * p)).mean())  # 0.8 to ensure that at least 80% of required data is present`
```

In addition, one helpful soul, Doralee requested *actual* data.  So please find a 60-day 2-stock excerpt below:

```
       efcode       date  liq_daily_usd     liq_daily  net_vwap_avg
2813  31160EF 2021-06-28   2.504318e+07  2.100057e+07  1.032595e+07
3116  40712SS 2021-06-29   3.160801e+04  2.706165e+05  1.965338e+05
2814  31160EF 2021-06-29   2.796293e+07  2.350023e+07  2.499666e+06
3117  40712SS 2021-06-30   1.381836e+05  1.187144e+06  9.165275e+05
2815  31160EF 2021-06-30   2.368039e+07  1.997603e+07 -3.524202e+06
2816  31160EF 2021-07-01   2.801560e+07  2.364225e+07  3.666223e+06
3118  40712SS 2021-07-01   3.228064e+05  2.780417e+06  1.593273e+06
2817  31160EF 2021-07-02   1.381241e+07  1.165624e+07 -1.198601e+07
3119  40712SS 2021-07-02   2.230596e+05  1.921271e+06 -8.591462e+05
2818  31160EF 2021-07-05   7.322225e+06  6.173102e+06 -5.483137e+06
3120  40712SS 2021-07-05   2.377546e+04  2.042565e+05 -1.717014e+06
3121  40712SS 2021-07-06   6.652910e+04  5.745172e+05  3.702608e+05
2819  31160EF 2021-07-06   1.878950e+07  1.589636e+07  9.723256e+06
3122  40712SS 2021-07-07   9.590548e+04  8.310700e+05  2.565528e+05
2820  31160EF 2021-07-07   1.300278e+07  1.102641e+07 -4.869949e+06
3123  40712SS 2021-07-08   3.023052e+04  2.610580e+05 -5.700120e+05
2821  31160EF 2021-07-08   2.374049e+07  2.004245e+07  9.016044e+06
3124  40712SS 2021-07-09   3.017735e+04  2.599255e+05 -1.132500e+03
2822  31160EF 2021-07-09   2.519673e+07  2.121902e+07  1.176562e+06
3125  40712SS 2021-07-12   3.026381e+03  2.611200e+04 -2.338135e+05
2823  31160EF 2021-07-12   1.963135e+07  1.655062e+07 -4.668400e+06
3126  40712SS 2021-07-13   1.675856e+03  1.456000e+04 -1.155200e+04
2824  31160EF 2021-07-13   1.897174e+07  1.610682e+07 -4.438000e+05
3127  40712SS 2021-07-14   7.188402e+04  6.223725e+05  6.078125e+05
2825  31160EF 2021-07-14   1.741195e+07  1.471287e+07 -1.393943e+06
3128  40712SS 2021-07-15   1.457851e+03  1.268800e+04 -6.096845e+05
2826  31160EF 2021-07-15   1.929207e+07  1.633523e+07  1.622360e+06
3129  40712SS 2021-07-16   2.724538e+04  2.375360e+05  2.248480e+05
2827  31160EF 2021-07-16   1.399231e+07  1.185287e+07 -4.482365e+06
2828  31160EF 2021-07-19   2.799721e+07  2.373188e+07  1.187901e+07
3130  40712SS 2021-07-19   5.629003e+04  4.916160e+05  2.540800e+05
3131  40712SS 2021-07-20   5.944235e+04  5.196010e+05  2.798500e+04
2829  31160EF 2021-07-20   1.913041e+07  1.623974e+07 -7.492146e+06
3132  40712SS 2021-07-21   2.807122e+04  2.447360e+05 -2.748650e+05
2830  31160EF 2021-07-21   2.461993e+07  2.087425e+07  4.634518e+06
3133  40712SS 2021-07-22   3.287703e+04  2.866350e+05  4.189900e+04
2831  31160EF 2021-07-22   2.213531e+07  1.880655e+07 -2.067700e+06
2832  31160EF 2021-07-23            NaN           NaN           NaN
3134  40712SS 2021-07-23   3.051708e+03  2.660600e+04 -2.600290e+05
3141  31160EF 2021-07-26   1.702820e+07  1.442701e+07 -3.147277e+06
3146  40712SS 2021-07-26   3.216440e+04  2.787210e+05  2.521150e+05
3147  40712SS 2021-07-27   4.222169e+04  3.658725e+05  8.715150e+04
3142  31160EF 2021-07-27   3.842427e+07  3.251885e+07  1.809184e+07
3143  31160EF 2021-07-28   3.321394e+07  2.804994e+07 -4.468907e+06
3148  40712SS 2021-07-28   5.818368e+04  5.028840e+05  1.370115e+05
3149  40712SS 2021-07-29   2.889200e+01  2.480000e+02 -5.026360e+05
3144  31160EF 2021-07-29   2.673023e+07  2.248468e+07 -5.565267e+06
3145  31160EF 2021-07-30   3.174899e+07  2.670631e+07  4.221629e+06
3150  40712SS 2021-07-30   8.643426e+03  7.419250e+04  7.394450e+04
3135  40712SS 2021-08-02   8.754480e+03  7.560000e+04  1.407500e+03
2833  31160EF 2021-08-02   1.883054e+07  1.586344e+07 -1.084286e+07
3136  40712SS 2021-08-03   5.831280e+03  5.040000e+04 -2.520000e+04
2834  31160EF 2021-08-03   1.541283e+07  1.299258e+07 -2.870867e+06
3137  40712SS 2021-08-04   1.823021e+04  1.575645e+05  1.071645e+05
2835  31160EF 2021-08-04   1.330210e+07  1.123963e+07 -1.752944e+06
3138  40712SS 2021-08-05   2.296201e+04  1.986333e+05  4.106885e+04
2836  31160EF 2021-08-05   1.577779e+07  1.333485e+07  2.095215e+06
2837  31160EF 2021-08-06   1.180542e+07  1.003777e+07 -3.297073e+06
3139  40712SS 2021-08-06   1.133002e+04  9.869352e+04 -9.993982e+04
3140  40712SS 2021-08-09   6.406671e+03  5.610045e+04 -4.259307e+04
```

Comment: can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (expected output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Salmonstrikes's code is doing right but not fast.
In this situtation, you should not use any "transform", "'table' method", or "'numba' speed up", you just need to do a simple rolling mean.
So I reduce some element of @Salmonstrikes's code, which runs faster.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *  #for BMonthEnd/MonthEnd()
import time


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    efcode = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10000),
    date = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(1990,1,1), end=pd.datetime(1990,1,1) + Day(9999), freq='D'),
    liq_daily = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000),
    liq_daily_usd = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000),
    net_vwap_avg = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000)
))

proc_list = ['liq_daily', 'liq_daily_usd', 'net_vwap_avg']

start_time=time.time()
for p in [3, 5, 10, 22, 45, 67, 125, 252, 504, 756, 1260]:
    df[[(q + '_' + str(p) + 'd') for q in proc_list]] = df.groupby('efcode')[proc_list].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(p, min_periods=int( 0.8 * p)).mean())
end_time=time.time()

print(f"Your origin execution time is: {end_time-start_time}")

df = df.sort_values(by=['efcode', 'date']).reset_index(drop=True)

df2=df.copy()

proc_list = ['liq_daily', 'liq_daily_usd', 'net_vwap_avg']

start_time=time.time()

for p in [3, 5, 10, 22, 45, 67, 125, 252, 504, 756, 1260]:
    df2[[f"{q}_{p}d" for q in proc_list]] = (
        df2
        .groupby('efcode')[proc_list]
        .rolling(p, min_periods=int(0.8 * p))
        .mean()
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
end_time=time.time()

print(f"My execution time is: {end_time-start_time}")

start_time=time.time()

for p in [3, 5, 10, 22, 45, 67, 125, 252, 504, 756, 1260]:
    df[[f"{q}_{p}d" for q in proc_list]] = (
        df
        .groupby('efcode')[proc_list]
        .rolling(p, min_periods=int(0.8 * p), method='table')
        .mean(engine='numba')
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
end_time=time.time()

print(f"Salmonstrikes execution time is: {end_time-start_time}")
```

[image: speed comparison]

Comment: On my machine (i9-9700k, win 10), my method takes 0.25s and yours and @Salmonstrikes both take 0.56.  Presumably due to different hardware? most helpful, I will run both as an example.  I used transform because it applies each period p's rolling to the whole selected dataframe, rather than to each column separately as with apply (presumably just using .rolling does something similar under the hood?)

Comment: I try a few times in my computer (i9-10885H, win10), the result is quite robust. It's quite weird.

Comment: Yes, just did a run on the European table (18869098 rows).  Results are below:


Your origin execution time is: 523.5300393104553
My execution time is: 1089.8778824806213
Salmonstrikes execution time is: 1081.2588078975677

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer for a narrow DF like this one. I've added some more background to my answer for the curious.

Comment: @Carl, I have tried 20m obs, here's the result: Carl's execution time is: 121.87030076980591; Doraelee's execution time is: 94.86659097671509; Consider your situtaion, I think there maybe two reasons why you are running different: 1, you may not keep the variables used, a smaller dataframe can reduce running time; 2, your computer should be enhanced, there are so much gap here.

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

@Doraelee 's answer is good: simple and gets the job done fast. After giving it some more thought and experimentation, I now realize that `method='table'` is more suited to very **wide** dataframes; i.e., with lots of columns. For narrow frames like in your case (3 columns), the performance boost from the vectorization and parallelism that happens across columns with `method='table'` is negligible.

I've included some more code below for benchmarking. You'll notice that the performance boost for the wide frame is larger than the boost for the narrow frame. In fact, `method='table'` can be *slower* on the narrow frame (as you've noticed yourself), and not just because of the compilation overhead. Perhaps Numba could be configured somehow to avoid this slowdown, or maybe there's just not a reliable implementation in Pandas yet -- I don't know.

Note that it's tough to compare the wide times against the narrow times because the complexity is quite different due to (i) the different lengths of groupings (ii) the parallelism invoked by Numba -- my vanilla Pandas `rolling.mean` appears to be serial-only by default.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


# it's tough to get apples-to-apples for wide vs narrow comparisons with parallelism on

num_wide_rows = 10 ** 4
num_wide_cols = 10 ** 4

num_narrow_cols = 10
num_narrow_rows = 10 ** 5

# seed generator
np.random.seed(22)
rolling_period = 14
min_periods = int(0.8 * rolling_period)

# create wide DF
wide_group_id_list = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10+1, size=num_wide_rows) # 10 possible groups
wide_group_id_list.sort()
wide_data = np.random.rand(num_wide_rows, num_wide_cols)
wide_df = pd.DataFrame(data=wide_data)
wide_df.insert(0, 'group_id', wide_group_id_list)

# create narrow DF
narrow_group_id_list = np.random.randint(low=1, high=10+1, size=num_narrow_rows) # 10 possible groups
narrow_group_id_list.sort()
narrow_data = np.random.rand(num_narrow_rows, num_narrow_cols)
narrow_df = pd.DataFrame(data=narrow_data)
narrow_df.insert(0, 'group_id', narrow_group_id_list)

def time_operation(title, df, method='single'):
    kwargs = {'engine': 'numba'} if method == 'table' else {}
    t_begin = datetime.now()
    for i in range(3): # repetitions
        df.groupby('group_id').rolling(rolling_period, min_periods=min_periods, method=method).mean(**kwargs)
    t_final = datetime.now()
    delta_t = t_final - t_begin
    print(f"'{title}' took {delta_t}.")

# (this step may be unnecessary) perform a cheap rolling mean in the hopes of smart, one-off precompilation for the timing test
narrow_df.head(2*min_periods).groupby('group_id').rolling(rolling_period, min_periods=min_periods, method='table').mean(engine='numba')

# timing experiment
time_operation('wide_df/method=single', wide_df, method='single')
time_operation('wide_df/method=table', wide_df, method='table')
time_operation('narrow_df/method=single', narrow_df, method='single')
time_operation('narrow_df/method=table', narrow_df, method='table')
```

Output from my laptop:

```
'wide_df/method=single' took 0:00:47.604131.
'wide_df/method=table' took 0:00:15.580090.
'narrow_df/method=single' took 0:00:00.365677.
'narrow_df/method=table' took 0:00:04.876920.
```

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

Here's some code that reproduces the results from your example, and uses the `table` method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *  #for BMonthEnd/MonthEnd()

np.random.seed(22) # basic reproducibility
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    efcode = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10000),
    date = pd.date_range(start=pd.datetime(1990,1,1), end=pd.datetime(1990,1,1) + Day(9999), freq='D'),
    liq_daily = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000),
    liq_daily_usd = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000),
    net_vwap_avg = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=10000)
))

proc_list = ['liq_daily', 'liq_daily_usd', 'net_vwap_avg']

# sort by efcode first, date next
df = df.sort_values(by=['efcode', 'date']).reset_index(drop=True)
    
for p in [3, 5, 10, 22, 45, 67, 125, 252, 504, 756, 1260]:
    df[[f"{q}_{p}d" for q in proc_list]] = (
        df
        .groupby('efcode')[proc_list]
        .rolling(p, min_periods=int(0.8 * p), method='table')
        .mean(engine='numba')
        .reset_index(drop=True)
    )
```

Points to note:

- For an apples-to-apples comparison, please sort the dataframe appropriately in your example as well
- The `table` method is currently only callable with the `numba` engine according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html#window-overview)

  - This means that the overhead from compilation might actually slow the code down for smaller dataframes like in this example; hopefully, you notice a speedup with larger datasets
- `efcode` remains in as the index as an outcome of the `groupby` operation -- this is why I reset and drop the index in the final step

Comment: Inspiring answer!